# Rendering elements from code-behind to v-html in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

How is it possible to get both the value and html from the code-behind to display effectively?

Example:

```
html: <div id="app" v-html="html"></div>

js: new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
      html: '<h1>Hello {{text}}</h1>',
      text: 'world'
      }
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lct8uz4o/214/

Tried using v-text, v-html, {{..}}, {{{..}}}, but nothing worked.

This is just an example, I have to display various div elements with different html syntax and each consist of a value(s) to be displayed. Can you help?

Below is the piece of code from the real issue:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-if="!isLoading" v-for="(f, index) in formatted">
    <td :class="c.ClassName" v-for="(c, index) in columnsDisplay" v-html="c.Description">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

columnsDisplay.push( 
{
   FieldName: "StateCode",
   ClassName: "tracking-state",
   Description: "{{f.StateCode}}"
},
{
   FieldName: "EnrollmentDate",
   ClassName: "tracking-enrolled",
   Description: "<span>{{f.EnrollmentDate}}</span><span class='tracking-cell-subtitle'> {{ f.TimeSinceEnrollment }}</span>"
},
{
   FieldName: "LastActivity",
   ClassName: "tracking-activity",
   Description: "<span>{{f.LastActivity}}</span><span class='tracking-cell-subtitle'>{{f.TimeSinceLastActivity}}</span></td>"
});
```

Comment: You should post a link for the code sample, instead of just a link for a code sample print.

Comment: Just posted the link. Kindly have a look and thanks for the feedback. @YagoAzedias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'world'
  },
  computed: {
    html: function() {
        return `<h1>Hello ${ this.text }</h1>`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app" v-html="html">
</div>
```

I couldn't find a source to indicate best practice, so perhaps you could also use [templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html), or something else entirely!

Comment: Yes that works in this example but in my condition each field has different values to be displayed -
<tbody>
  <tr v-if="!isLoading" v-for="(f, index) in formatted">
    <td :class="c.ClassName" v-for="(c, index) in columnsDisplay" v-html="c.Description">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

columnsDisplay.push( 
{
FieldName: "StateCode",
ClassName: "tracking-state",
Description: "{{f.StateCode}}"
},
{
FieldName: "EnrollmentDate",
ClassName: "tracking-enrolled",
Description: "<span>{{f.EnrollmentDate}}</span><span class='tracking-cell-subtitle'> {{ f.TimeSinceEnrollment }}</span>"
});

Comment: @SindhuG Hmmm, I'm not convinced it wouldn't work if you use computed methods instead of inserting the values into strings. ex: Description: {{ computedDescription }}. I haven't tried however so I can't prove it... have you? :)

Comment: Also, *disclaimer*: Not a Vue.js expert -->